# lambda string order by dates with number

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

How to sort this?

I have List of string with values like this

```
11-03-2013
11-03-2013 -Count=2
11-03-2013 -count=1

11-04-2013 -Count=1
11-04-2013 -Count=2
11-04-2013
```

Output should be, The one without the count should be on the last and the top most should be 1 followed by 1 and dates should be ordered by ascending.

```
11-03-2013 -Count=2
11-03-2013 -count=1
11-03-2013

11-04-2013 -Count=2
11-04-2013 -Count=1
11-04-2013
```

I tried this code but this is sorting this by descending

```
var  edates= edates.OrderBy(e => e.Replace("-count=1", string.Empty).Replace("-count=2", string.Empty)).ToList();
```

I know that a simple class with properties can do the trick but doing that so would need to change other methods which would require a lot of work.

Regards

Comment: @muctadir thanks for correcting the formatting

Comment: create to functions: first substrings date part and parses it and second substrings the count part and returns parsed count(or 0 if length < 9) and then `yourList.OrderBy(s=> f1(s)).ThenBy(s=> f2(s))`

Comment: @GuruStron I appreciate if you can give the code if possible. sorry for the spoon feeding.

Comment: at all I appreciate the amount of help. :-) let me go through the codes.

Comment: @GuruStron your idea was the best, I implemented it code, hope I did it justice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is @Guru Stron's solution in code

```
private static void sortList()
{
    var dates = getDates();
    var sorted = dates.OrderBy(f1).ThenByDescending(f2);
}

private static DateTime f1(string parse)
{
    return DateTime.Parse(parse.Substring(0, 10));
}

private static int f2(string parse)
{
    int sort;
    if (parse.Length > 10) int.TryParse(parse.Substring(18), out sort);
    else sort = 0;
    return sort;
}
```

Comment: output is becoming the first value should be 2 instead of 1.
what happens now is:
11-04-2013 -Count=1
11-04-2013 -Count=2
11-04-2013

Comment: Make sure you have my last edit.  I changed the code to `ThenByDescending` to sort the second section and returned default sort as 0 instead of 100.

Comment: @paqogomez, great correction about `ThenByDescending`, but for parsing may be better `parse.Substring(18)` in case of big counts

Comment: i added the thenbydescending(f2) but the result is 11-04-2013 followed by 11-04-2013 -Count=1  then by 11-04-2013 -Count=2

Comment: @Mico again, its my edit timing.  Check `else sort = 0;` it should say 0 not 100

Comment: @paqogomez wait i think i missed something

Comment: @Mico I'm at a loss, its working perfectly on my end.  Are the strings you are parsing 18 chars long?  I'll add my GetDates() method so you can see exactly what i'm doing.

Comment: @paqogomez thank you for saving my day. :-) its great and it is working

Comment: Thanks Guru Stron and paqogomez. How i wish i can accept both of your solutions. i really appreciate the time youve spent with me.

Comment: @Mico, np, paqogomez done the job and spent more time) was glad to help)

Answer (score 3):

it is because you compare strings not dates. Create two functions: first substrings date part and parses it and second substrings the count part and returns parsed count(or 0 if length < 11) and then `yourList.OrderBy(s=> f1(s)).ThenByDescending(s=> f2(s))`

Comment: sorry im kinda confused. Are you saying that i would iterate on the list and parse one by one the edates?

Comment: @Mico Check out my implementation of Guru Stron's idea

Comment: @Mico, yes, definitely. Sorry, for delay, as i see there are a lot of code examples for parsing, so i won't provide mine. If your have a lot of values for the same date you can consider first `.GroupBy(s => s.Substring(0, 10))` and then parsing and ordering by it, but not sure that this will be much faster, but to get correct ordering you still need to parse dates and counts

Answer (score 1):

You first need to order by the date, then by the rest of the string, descending;

```
    edates =
        edates.OrderBy(x => 
               DateTime.ParseExact(x.Substring(0, 10), "MM-dd-yyyy", 
               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            .ThenByDescending(x => x.Substring(10))
            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should order as desired across *different years* and *counts >= 10*.

This won't be the "fastest" method (and it will most certainly not work with L2S/EF LINQ providers), but it should sort the given format correctly *and* fail-fast on invalid values. I would likely write the code like this (or use an `IComparer` with an equivalent setup) - mainly because it "reads simple" to me.

```
DateTime OrderableItem (string e) {
    var date = e.Substring(0, 10);
    return DateTime.ParseExact(date, "MM-dd-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
}

int OrderableCount (string e) {
    var m = Regex.Match(e, @"-count=(\d+)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    return m.Success
        ? int.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value)
        : 0;
}

var res = seq.OrderBy(OrderableDate)
             .ThenBy(OrderableCount);
```

I much prefer to *take* data, instead of excluding data.

Comment: This handles the date sort, but not the `count=x` sort.

Answer (score 0):

You ought to use a real class to simplify things and have a proper representation. That said, you can use the LINQ query syntax and take advantage of the `let` clause to store the result of splitting the text on a space and the equal symbol. If the split result has more than one element we can assume the count exists. Next, we order by the date (after parsing it) and then by parsing the count (descending).

Try this approach out:

```
string[] inputs = 
{
    "11-03-2013",
    "11-03-2013 -Count=2",
    "11-03-2013 -Count=1",
    "11-04-2013 -Count=1",
    "11-04-2013 -Count=2",
    "11-04-2013"
};

var query = from input in inputs
            let split = input.Split(' ', '=')
            let count = split.Length > 1 ? int.Parse(split[2]) : 0
            orderby DateTime.Parse(split[0]), count descending
            select input;

foreach (var item in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```